# Misunderstood Compiler Error on glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

Tags: opengl

error: there are no arguments to 'glGenerateMipmap' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'glGenerateMipmap' must be available [-fpermissive]

I have #include `<GL/glext.h>` included and can see the declaration of the function in the header, however I get the compiler error above. I am on Ubuntu 13.04 with the most up-to-date nvidia drivers installed. I would assume that this function would be defined.

My use of the function is:

```
  if (mipmapped) {
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  }
```

Why is my compiler choking on this function? What does that error mean in this context?

Comment: Best guess is to try using the `glxGetProcAddress` rout and see if you get a better result. I typically work with Windows, and on windows you need to use `wglGetProcAddress` otherwise you get a similar error. Though I'm not a Ubuntu user yet, so I dont know what's different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `glext.h` header does by default *not* declare those functions, you have to

```
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
```

before including that file if you really want to. But you should be warned that just declaring that function is does not mean that you can successfully link on any platform, as the GL lib is not required to export that function. On Linux, it is likely to work, though, but the closest to a standard is the [OpenGL Application Binary Interface for Linux](http://www.opengl.org/registry/ABI/) which just guarantees that all OpenGL 1.2 core functions are exported.

You should consider using the OpenGL extension mechanism, either manually via `glXGetProcAddress[ARB]()` or by using a convenient library like [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) or [GL3W](https://github.com/shakesoda/gl3w).

Comment: I have extracted the logic from glew myself because glew is not supported on all linux distributions (aka RHEL 5 and possibly 6). What is the fucntion pointer I need?

example: # define  glGetProcAddress(arg) glXGetProcAddress((const GLubyte*)arg)
#endif

extern PFNGLBLENDFUNCSEPARATEPROC glBlendFuncSeparate;

// GL_ARB_shader_objects
extern PFNGLCREATESHADERPROC glCreateShader;

Comment: @Matthew Hoggan: I don't see why glew should not work on those RHEL platforms (although I never try it). Howerver, to do it manually, glext.h defines function pointer types for any of the extension functions with the prefix PFN followed by the exact function name, all in upper case, so in your case, you can declare `PFNGLGENERATEMIPMAP myGenerateMipmap;`. After you got the context, you can query it via `myGenerateMipmap=(PFNGLGENERATEMIPMAP)glXGetProcaddress("glGenerateMipmap");` and after that, just call `myGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` or whatever.

Comment: auto code complete was not working I guess. PFNGLGENERATEMIPMAPPROC is the name of the function pointer. Please update your answer above so I can mark your answer as the correct response.